# The throuput of Nginx reverse proxy Resin

Tags: nginx, resin

We are using nginx+resin to serve a jsp website.
my question is when many requests from web client to ngix and then nginx requests resin, so I want to know:
Does resin response the data to clients Or Nginx get the data from resin and then response to the Clients.
if ngix get data from resin and then response data to clients, but why I use top command could
 not see many cpu and memory resources be occupied by Nginx, but resin was occupying many resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx acts as proxy. It doesn't require a lot of memory and cpu to proxying data between client(browser) and backend(resin). It doesn't do any work except copy data between source and destination, but do such type of work damn fast, so you can't see nginx in top.
So if you don't use another advantages of nginx, such as caching and very fast serving of static files, in your configuration it's absolutely useless.

Comment: Yes,I think maybe Nginx uses a IO Channel directly transfer resin data to client,so doesn't occupy the memory and CPU. Nginx like a bridge between source stream and destination stream.
Thank you very much CyberDemOn :)